# VB.NET data-bound combobox doesn't update correctly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox that should display a list of files we get from clients for the user to select from, with the option of just active clients or all clients. The client file list is part of a SQL Server database which I've added as a data source to my project (using VS 2010). It initially displays the list correctly, but when I check off the radio button to only show active groups, nothing happens. What am I missing?

```
Private Sub activegroups_radiobox_Checked(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles activegroups_radiobox.Click
    'use sql command to display all active company names, ordered by company, in the combobox
    Using myconnection As New SqlConnection("connection string")
        Dim activegroups As String = "SELECT File_Name FROM ClientFileDatabase WHERE ClientStatus != 'Terminated' ORDER BY File_Name;"
        Dim activegroups_sqlcommand As New SqlCommand(activegroups, myconnection)

        Dim activegroups_dataadapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        activegroups_dataadapter.SelectCommand = activegroups_sqlcommand

        Dim activegroups_dataset As DataSet = New DataSet()
        activegroups_dataadapter.Fill(activegroups_dataset, "ClientFileDatabase")
        Dim activegroups_dataview = New DataView(activegroups_dataset.Tables("ClientFileDatabase"))
        client_selection_combobox.DataSource = activegroups_dataset
        client_selection_combobox.DisplayMember = "File_Name"
    End Using
End Sub
```

I tried googling and don't think I'm missing any steps here, but obviously something's off. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `GotFocus` is probably the wrong time to do that.  Try it in the OnLoad override.

Comment: Realized I had an old sub still hanging around which caused the issue...but having a different one now, see the edit

Comment: `Clicked` isn't quite the same as the `CheckChanged` event.  When using the `CheckChanged` event, you want to first see that the control's checked value is returning true.  I assume your DataSource should be `client_selection_combobox.DataSource = activegroups_dataview`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the radio button list is set to AutoPostBack = True and make your sub handle CheckChanged. You will then have to check each radio button to see if it is selected and filter the data being supplied appropriately.

Comment: Changed the sub handle, but don't see any option to declare AutoPostBack...is that an ASP thing?

Comment: Ok, set "AutoCheck" to true, but the button is not checked when I go to debug. Really starting to wonder what's going on...

Comment: My mistake on the autopostback, wasn't sure if you were using a web or win form. The CheckChanged option should fire any time the is a change to it's checked property. You should then be able apply your logic to see if it is or is not checked and apply the appropriate action. If you are saying that when you click it, it is not checking, then you may have issues in your code that are resetting its value. Try clicking twice to see if that affects it as well (once to set focus and again to change the value).

Comment: It does check when I click it, but the client file list just doesn't update as a result of that (even if I click twice).

Comment: Try throwing a .Refresh() after you update the data source. 
        client_selection_combobox.Refresh()